# What does "like" mean in "What’s your schedule like next week?"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What does "like" mean in "What’s your schedule like next week?"

Can I say that without ‘LIKE’?

Answer (score 1):

*To be like X* means to be similar to X or to have many attributes in common with X.

Asking what X is like means you want a summary or overview of X, and not the exact X.

Examples:

> Q: What’s your schedule like next week?

> A: I have a lot of free time and I can be flexible.

versus

> Q: What's your schedule next week?

> A: Available 10a-5p M-F, except Tuesday from 3p-4p.